# Posting data to URL with Android Volley not working

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I want to post some data to a url, then get the posted data from that url and store it in a database. I've tried to echo the posted params but they appear not to have been posted and no error is shown.
Below is the function I use to do the post:

```
public void insertDataWithVolley() {
        String url = "http://apps.example.com/application/index.php/main/getParamsFromVolley";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> mapObject = new HashMap<>();
                mapObject.put("id", "ID");
                Log.d("TAG", "Put id");
                mapObject.put("name", "NAME");
                Log.d("TAG", "Put name");
                return mapObject;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

On the PHP side, this is the function, see below:

```
public function getParamsFromVolley() {
        $id = null;
        $name = null;

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id= $this->input->get('id');
        }
        if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
            $name= $this->input->get('name');
        }
        //store $pesapal_tracking_id in your database against the order with orderid = $reference09
        echo 'name>>>>' . $id; 
        echo 'email>>>>' . $name;               

        //return $pesapal_tracking_id;
    }
```

Kindly assist

Comment: your url looks a bit suspect -- (http://apps.example.com/application/index.php/main/getParamsFromVolley)

Comment: Hi, I can access other stuff from the url apart from getting. I've edited the question to include the server side function that I'm calling.

Comment: It will help if you post the URL

Comment: here: http://apps.silvapalace.com/smsking/index.php/main/getParamsFromVolley

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP but you are checking GET in PHP while your are making POST request in Volley. Change PHP code to check POST params.

```
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id= $this->input->get('id');
    }
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name= $this->input->get('name');
    }
```

Also make a simple html page to check if your post request is working after the change.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't bring the desired results even after editing it to a POST

Comment: @Kabs -- try and echo a single result and split it at the other end -- eg (echo 'name>>>>' . $id.  #'email>>>>' . $name;) and split to # character. Other things you can try is to tail your PHP/apache error log file and see if you get any errors with your php script when you make the volley request

Comment: @Kabs As I said above, problem is with your PHP code. First make sure you are handling a POST request before you try it in Android application. You can use sample HTML form to try making Post request to get it right.